# как сложить два массива в цикле?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3,4,5]
$b = [3,4,5,6,7]
?>
```

есть два массива
как их сложить в цикле ? чтобы первый элемент массива $a, добавлялся к первому элементу массива $b и так далее

Answer (score 1):

Вариант "разобраться на досуге":

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [3,4,5,6,7];
$c = array_map('array_sum', array_map(null, $a, $b));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. определяете третий массив
2. выполняете цикл `for-i` с количеством итераций равным количеству элементов в массиве
3. складываете элементы массива находящиеся на одних и тех же позициях в массивах `$a` и `$b`
4. сохраняете их в третий массив на ту же позицию

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [3,4,5,6,7];
$c = [];

for($i=0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    $c[$i] = $a[$i] + $b[$i];
}

print_r($c);
?>
```

**ВЫВОД:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 12
)
```